# When calling an IEnumerable over a WCF Service I receive The underlying connection was closed error

Tags: c#, wcf

Bit of background on my question...

I have a website and multiple console apps that access the same data layer (Linq-To-Sql) to set/get data.  The console apps run across our network and they all update the central database via WCF services.  The website is used to display the data captured by the apps data to the users.

My WCF services works when I'm returning simple types and when I'm returning lists of my custom objects BUT my service falls over with an 'underlying connection was closed error' whenever I try and return anything within an IEnumerable/IQueryable.

I thought it was possible to return IEnumerables/IQueryables over WCFs services ?  Is is possible, or, am I just configuring my service wrong ?  I'm using basicHttpBinding instead of wsHttpBinding but I'm still not 100% in what situation it is best to use the different types.

My set-up is like this :

```
public class CageService : ICageRepository
{
        public IEnumerable<Cage> GetAll()
        {
            var dc = new DataContext();
            return dc .GetAll();
        }
}


[ServiceContract]
public interface ICageRepository : IRepository<Cage>
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Cage> GetAll();

}
```

Service Config :

```
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
      <service name="CageService" behaviorConfiguration="CageServiceTypeBehaviors" >
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost/UHFWebsite/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
        <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />


        <endpoint address ="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Wavin.CageTracking.DataLayer.Interfaces.ICageRepository" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CageServiceTypeBehaviors" >
          <!-- Add the following element to your service behavior configuration. -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Client config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICageRepository1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />


          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:2000/UHFServices/CageService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICageRepository1"
        contract="CageRepositoryClient.ICageRepository" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICageRepository1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

calling code looks like:

```
void method()
{
            var client = new CageRepositoryClient();
            CageListView.DataSource = client.GetAll();;
            CageListView.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the Cage class to the known types of your service in the implementation of your interface.

```
[ServiceBehavior]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Cage))] 
public class CageRepository: ICageRepository
{
...
```

Comment: `Cage` may already be a known type, there is nothing to indicate that its not.

Comment: Just out of interest..  could you explain why the service will return a list of objects fine but won't return a list of IEnumerbale objects without first declaring the object as a known type ?

Comment: Is specifying this service behavior different than declaring Cage as a [DataContract] with [DataMember] properties and fields?

Comment: @StealthRabbi Yes, that is something completely different! Declaring a Type as ServiceKnownType still requires you to add the DataContract and DataMember attributes to the Cage class.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like to you do not call `ToList()` on the data you get back from your data context. This is usually the cause of the problem with ORMs as what you return is not data but the query itself.

So you need to use:

```
dataContext.All().ToList();
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to type the returning call (if possible) which is why I would prefer to return the query instead of a list.  If I added .ToList() I would then be returning a List isntead of an IEnumerable.

Comment: List<T> is castable to IEnumerable. Either way your problem is the wcf connection is closed before you attempt to enumerate the query. You need to enuemrate it before the connection is toast, ie call .ToList() or something on it so you have the real data instead of the query.

Comment: @Jon, why do you want to return an `IEnumerable`?  I assume you are not interested in the deferred execution possibilities, as that would be nonsensical over a WCF service call.  As asawyer mentions, a `List<T>` is compatible with an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: WCF turns the IEnumerable into an array anyway.

Comment: The website will skip the WCF service and access the data layer directly.  The data layer and the service use the same interface so the methods have the same signatures.  When I'm using the website I don't really need to type anything which is why I odn't just turn everythig to a list as it adds uneeded code.... BUT if what every is saying is that I can't return IEnumerables over a WCF service then I can change it.

Comment: You can return IEnumerable from a WCF call easily. Cast down your result list to Ienumerable, or loop through and yeild return the list as an iterator. Just don't do it with the WCF query.

Comment: If you really object that much to your data being returned as a list instead of a generic enumerable, then instead of `ToList()` use either `ToArray()` or `ToList().AsEnumerable<Cage>()`. The main point is that you have to force enumeration before returning your results, otherwise the DataContext is out of scope when the query actually tries to hit your database. It's also better as far as database resources; this way all the results get returned at once. Doing a `yield return` within the scope of your DataContext would hold a lock in the database while your results are being iterated.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason this simple change isn't working? If so what is the error?

```
public IEnumerable<Cage> GetAll()
{
    var dc = new DataContext();
    return dc.GetAll().ToList();
}
```

Edit- I get the impression from your post that you may think that IEnumerable is a linq query. This is not the case, it is simple a sequence of items of type T.

This is perfectly valid statement that creates an IEnumerable from a a List object for instance.

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Comment: You were spot on with your answer as I I did't consdier that List could be derived from IEnumerable.  The only issue I had with it is that I would have added ToList() on every method I was returning as IEnumerable. BUT.. it did allow me to continue using the interface and the website in the way I wanted.  My final solution was Flo's one